# Cannot Get Correct Value in Dropdownlist In ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am working on project where I need to select value from my asp dropdown list which comes from MySql Database as below: [Mysql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYVan.png) from where dropdown list is coming from.

Here is my UI Looks Like: [Selecting Value which came from Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mevSt.png).

Here is my ASPX file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MASTER_USER.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Ask_user.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ask_user" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="container">

<form class="form-horizontal" >
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<h1 align=center>ASK YOUR QUESTION!</h1>



<!-- Multiple Radios -->
<div class="form-group space">
  <label style="text-align:right;" class="col-md-4 control-label">Category</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Topics</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
     </div><br />

 </div>

 <label style="text-align:right;" class="col-md-4 control-label">Sub Category</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Sub topics</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
     </div><br />

 </div>
<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group space">
  <label style="text-align:right;" class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Title ">Title</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="title" name="title" runat="server"  placeholder="What is your question?" class="form-control input-md"  type="text">

  </div><br />
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group space">
  <label style="text-align:right;" class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Disc">Description</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">                    
    <textarea class="form-control" id="Disc" runat="server" name="Disc" placeholder="A brief description about your question..."></textarea>
    <br />


    <asp:Button ID="btn_ask" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="ASK!"
                    OnClick="btn_insert_Click" />
                    <span id="msg" ></span>
  </div>
</div>



</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is my cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public partial class Ask_user : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    dbconnection con = new dbconnection("connect_to_mysql");
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect_to_mysql"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string qry = "select cat_nm, cat_id from category";
            DataTable dt = dbconnection.ExecuteSelect(qry);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "cat_nm";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "cat_id";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {


            string catval = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            string qry = "select * from category_sub where parent_id = " +  catval;
            DataTable dt = dbconnection.ExecuteSelect(qry);
            DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "cat_nm";
            DropDownList2.DataValueField = "cat_sub";
            DropDownList2.DataBind();    


        }
    }
    protected void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string cat2 = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;

        int sb = (Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToInt32(cat2)));
        string cat = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        string title1 = title.Value.ToString();
        string disc = Disc.Value.ToString();

        string uid = (Session["uid"].ToString());

        string query = @"insert into question(cat_sub,catg,question,q_dis,user_id)values('" + sb + "','" + cat + "','" + title1.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + disc.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + uid + "')";

        dbconnection.ExecuteInsert(query);

        string info = "Success";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alert", "$('#msg').addClass('alert alert-success');$('#msg').text('" + info + "');",true);


    }
}
```

Here is my problem that value of `cat_sub` is always coming `11` rather then `12` were same as above oracle / mysql values are coming `8` rather then it's respective `cat_sub`.

While debugging values are coming is only first from there value's. Here is some info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lcq2.png.

Comment: you can add code directly to your question instead of posting it on pastebin.

Comment: What is the intended working?  I only count 11 items instead of the 12 you mention

Comment: cat_sub value coming as "12" even when you select "Switching" from the sub-category dropdownlist ?

Comment: No cat_sub coming as 11 even i am select "Switching" @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 0):

your child cateogry binding code running too when button clickted and refresh selected childcategory before button code event.

remove it from `Page_Load`.

add selectedIndexChanged event to DropDownList1

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

and handle..

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string catval = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        string qry = "select * from category_sub where parent_id = " +  catval;
        DataTable dt = dbconnection.ExecuteSelect(qry);
        DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "cat_nm";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "cat_sub";
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Still not coming value 12 ... only first one is displaying.